# jQuery 1.4.3 selector problem in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to get an element like so:

```
var billingID = 'table[id^="table.form.billingaddress"] #'+ shippingID;
var billingName = $(billingID).attr("name");
```

It works as I'd expect in FF, Chrome, IE8, IE9 but IE7 gives me 'undefined'

Help will be greatly appreciated. ... and I'm stuck with the way IDs are generated in the document :-(

Comment: what does your 'name' attribute look like. What does your shippingID look like too? Maybe you have invalid characters that ie7 is tripping over which the newer browsers are handling gracefully.

Comment: table id: table.form.billingaddress.0
shippingID: nameFirst
expected name: nameFirst

Comment: Is it possible to see a sample of the markup

Comment: ... here's the markup on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HenriPablo/qJTnU/1/

Comment: Anyone else not seeing the resize handle between the javascript and HTML on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This code works in IE 7.0.5730.13:

```
<table id="table.form.billingaddress.0">
    <div id="nameFirst"></div>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // alerts with "table.form.billingaddress.0"
       alert($('table[id^="table.form.billingaddress"]')[0].id);
       // alerts with "nameFirst"
       alert($('table[id^="table.form.billingaddress"] #nameFirst')[0].id);
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure why this is working at all, the periods in the table id should be [escaped](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector
>   $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: ... good point, I don't know why it works, I'm just enjoying the fact that it does :-) I'll fix it though. So, just got the mess working like so:
var x = 'table[id^="table.form.billingaddress"]';
alert( $(x).find('#'+ shippingID).attr("name") );

... and it's working cross browser, even ie7 :-)